# Big empty space at bottom of webpage? Can't seem to isolate the guilty CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been setting up a very basic Wordpress site. All of the pages have a lot of empty space at the bottom. Pages with more placeholder content have more space at the bottom than the others.

I have been reading other threads from people with similar problems, and I can't fix the problem on my site using suggested fixes (the margin property in a certain div was often the culprit).

Check it out: http://www.hairofthedogproductions.co.nz/?page_id=5

My client wanted a totally minimal bare-bones site so I have collapsed post/page metadata, comments, and the sidebar. I just can't for the life of me get rid of the big empty space at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is in the comments template. I see you're using `visibility: collapse` to hide elements, but `collapse` is just for table elements, and if used in other tags it'll default to `hidden`. Plus, keep in mind that `visibility: hidden` hides elements but keeps them in flow. You might want to use `display: none` instead.
This will solve your problem, try it out.

```
#comments { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate your page: http://validator.w3.org

I validated it and found about a dozen errors (some of them potentially serious enough to break the layout of the page, such as an unterminated tag).

When inspecting the source in Chrome, the element in the blank area was the `HTML` tag itself, which might indicate an overall failure to determine the correct document structure--the parser tries but can't always determine what you want it to do when there are malformed tags.

Comment: gosh, completely forgot to validate my page. As you can tell I am a real Greenhorn. Thanks for your advice, I will clean up the tags and remember to validate all my pages in the future.

Comment: @Sceneman - no problem. It may not fix the issue, but it will sure help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply overflow:hidden on your main wrapper then it will remove all blank space at the bottom

```
#main {
overflow: hidden;
}
```